# Can Linux provide an execve user-space callback?

Tags: inotify

In the past I've employed *inotify* for logging and as well as system functions.  Now I'm in a position where I need to know each time an executable has been called, and a complete set of command line arguments passed in.

Short of setting up an auditd rule, is there any method to trigger on a particular executable being called, and return its command line arguments from user-space?  I know the audit daemon can do this, so perhaps that's where I should look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Monitoring process creation and termination events is a useful skill to have in you toolbox. This article consists of two parts. The first introduces exiting tools for diffrent platforms. The second explains how these tools work internally. [1](https://jarekprzygodzki.dev/post/monitor-new-process-creation/)

[1](https://jarekprzygodzki.dev/post/monitor-new-process-creation/) describes many tools, one tool named `forkstat` which uses the `netlink`[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink) and [source code](https://github.com/ColinIanKing/forkstat)

Here are commands I used:

```
git clone https://github.com/ColinIanKing/forkstat.git
cd forkstat
make
sudo ./forkstat
```

In a separate ssh session I ran an ls command and observed this output:

```
Time     Event   PID Info   Duration Process
09:43:49 fork  10362 parent          -bash
09:43:49 fork  10433 child           -bash
09:43:49 exec  10433                 ls --color=auto
09:43:49 exit  10433      0   0.004s ls --color=auto
```